# How to reverse a paged datasource using EF core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use the following code to get paged data in the data grid (EF Core 6):

```
using (var _sqliteContext = new SQLiteContext())
{
   AssociatedObject.LoadDynamicItems(e.StartIndex, await _sqliteContext.Equipments
                   .Include(x => x.CostCenter)
                   .Include(x => x.EqInfo)
                   .Skip(e.StartIndex)
                   .Take(e.PageSize)
                   .ToListAsync());
}
```

I want to reverse the order of the whole data meaning the last data added is shown on the first page by default.
I tried to use `.TakeLast(e.PageSize)` but It causes a runtime error and cannot be translated.

How can I do it?

**Update:**
I want the newer data to be on the first pages. New data are detected based on incrementing IDs.

Comment: How do you define "last"? How do you want to _order_ your results?

Comment: An incrementing Id number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order the records in your query before you attempt to page it. You've said that the higher the Id column is (some number), the newer it is.

```
await _sqliteContext.Equipments
    .Include(x => x.CostCenter)
    .Include(x => x.EqInfo)
    .OrderByDecending(x => x.Id) // <- ordering results, newest first
    .Skip(e.StartIndex)
    .Take(e.PageSize)
    .ToListAsync());
```